# Group data to reduce the autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Suppose $X_n=\phi X_{n-1}+e_n$, where $X_0=\mu_o=0$, $\phi$ is the model coefficient, and $e_n$ are white noise with $\sigma_e=1$. Assume that $\phi=0.5$ and sample correlation between $(X_{n-1},X_n)$ is 0.5. Now, define $Y_j=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^pX_{(j-1)p+i}$.

Assuming $p=0.5$, how can one show that the correlation between $(Y_j,Y_{j-1})$ is 0.148 and sample standard deviation is 1.155?

Comment: I need a mathematical formulation for this.

Comment: What formulas for correlation do you know?  What problems did you run into when applying them?

Comment: I used the traditional formula given in most time series books.

Comment: I don't know what that "traditional formula" might be.  Note that this question asks you to compute the correlation between two random variables $Y_j$ and $Y_{j-1}$ that are defined as linear combinations of the $X_n$.  Perhaps your formula will help you compute covariances of the $X_n$, which are what you need to compute covariances (whence you obtain correlations) of the $Y_j$.

Comment: here is the information to compute it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation  http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35c.htm https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/60

Comment: That reference doesn't indicate what you might mean by a "traditional formula," but you might still find it helpful to emulate its methods of computing variances and covariances: they apply to your question.

Comment: I applied but could not get the required answers.